# How to make clear screen of cmd in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

I did not find any command to make clear the cmd screen. I am working on SQLite.

Any command available in `sqlite3` to make this clear.

There is lot of rush on the cmd screen.

I tried to find out by `.help` command but there is nothing.

I am working on WINDOWS.

Comment: if all else fails, you have a clear command in your computer's shell. (cls for windows & clear for everything else)

Comment: not working i have tried it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got temporary solution for that..

```
sqlite> press ctrl+d enter
```

it will show root

```
root@android:/ #
```

again

```
root@android:/ #  ctrl+d enter
```

now you ll get path of drive in which you have platform-tools.

this is like this

`F:\AndroidSDK\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>` cls command enter.

you ll get cmd screen clear.

Answer (score 6):

When you write `.shell` you can then write any `cmd` command
example: `.shell cls`

Comment: By the way =): on unix-based systems it would be `.shell clear`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to display the escape sequence for clearing the screen (`Esc[2J`):

```sql
SELECT CAST(x'1B5B324A' AS TEXT);
```

This works only if your terminal interprets ANSI/VT100 escape sequences, i.e., in Linux.